# Parse ldap filter to escape special characters

Tags: java, regex, parsing, active-directory, ldap

An ejb service takes a ldap filter as string and returns a result from ActiveDirectory.

The problem is that sometimes attribute values contain special characters that need to be escaped for the entire filter as specified here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx

and for distinguished name attibute values as specified here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366101(v=vs.85).aspx

In order to accomplish this the service must do the following:

1. Analyze the string for dn values, separate them and escape them as per dn escape rules if they are not already escaped.
2. Search the remainder of the string for special characters in attribute values and escape them as per general filter escape rules if they are not already escaped.
3. Combine the results as the new escaped filter and pass it on.

Java native `javax.naming.ldap.Rdn` escapes dn values all right but is not idempotent. As for the other tasks, so far I have been unable to find a library that would allow me to accomplish them.

Right now I am inclined to think that the job of escaping the ldap filter should be done by the user of the service rather than by the service itself as it is very hard for the service to tell escapes from actual values. Also, parsing a complex string such as a ldap filter without a well tested library seems to me error prone.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Can this task be automated at all?

Comment: Does this really need doing fi you supply the arguments via the `{0}` mechanism?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For escaping LDAP filters, I relied on this page to write the code below: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx#Special_Characters

```
String LdapEscape(String ldap)
{
    if(ldap == null) return "";
    return ldap.replace("\\", "\\5C").replace("*", "\\2A").replace("(", "\\28").replace(")", "\\29").replace("\000", "\\00");
}
```

The most important thing to keep in mind here is that replacing `\` with `\5C` must happen first so that you don't double escape any characters. Otherwise it's very straightforward; there aren't any special tricks to watch out for.

I'd like to point out that this is meant to escape individual values placed in LDAP filters, not the entire LDAP filter. However if you wanted, you could use that function to escape something like this so it can be searched for:

```
LdapEscape("(!(sn=m*))"); // \28!\28sn=m\2A\29
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer by Pluto is great and concise, but non-ASCII UTF-8 characters (e.g. é, á, ö, etc.) need special handling too.  Here's my verbose solution.

```
/** 
 * Filter components need to escape special chars.
 * Note that each piece of the filter needs to be escaped, 
 * not the whole filter expression, for example:
 * 
 * "(&(cn="+ esc("Admins") +")(member="+ esc("CN=Doe\\, Jöhn,OU=ImPeople,DC=ds,DC=augur,DC=com") +"))"
 * 
 * @see Oracle Directory Server Enterprise Edition 11g Reference doc
 * @see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29127_01/doc.111170/e28969/ds-ldif-search-filters.htm#gdxoy
 * @param s A String field within the search expression
 * @return The escaped string, safe for use in the search expression.
 */
public static String esc(String s)
{
    if(s == null) return "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length());
    for (byte c : s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    {
        if (c=='\\') { sb.append("\\5c"); }
        else if (c=='*') { sb.append("\\2a"); }
        else if (c=='(') { sb.append("\\28"); }
        else if (c==')') { sb.append("\\29"); }
        else if (c==0) { sb.append("\\00"); }
        else if ((c&0xff)>127) { sb.append("\\").append(to2CharHexString((c))); } // UTF-8's non-7-bit characters, e.g. é, á, etc...
        else { sb.append((char)c); }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

/** 
 * @return The least significant 16 bits as a two-character hex string, 
 * padded by a leading '0' if necessary.
 */
public static String to2CharHexString(int i)
{
    String s = Integer.toHexString(i & 0xff);
    if (s.length()==1) return "0"+s;
    else return s;
}
```

Comment: what about the `/` character?

Comment: Per this site, the forward slash does not need to be escaped: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5312.active-directory-characters-to-escape.aspx#LDAP_Filters

Comment: it definitely needs escaped when it's part of a DN. that's what brought me here anyways

Comment: Yes... If you scroll to the top of the link I sent, check out the "Active Directory" and "ADSI" sections.  They explain what needs to be escaped for DNs, and that the forward slash needs to be escaped only when you use an ADSI interface. (Hopefully it can't hurt if you escape too much, to be safe.)

The code I posted was only for escaping characters used in a filter, not a DN.  (Rant: IMHO, all these varying escape rules signify a fragile protocol design, but it's too late now.)

Comment: Suggestions for code improvement: (1) it's not necessary to `& 0xff` twice, both in the call and in the helper-method and (2) string-concatenation is "expensive". With a pre-defined `char[]` array you can simply index into it for a one-liner which is very fast.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz, good point about the extra &0xff... I edited the code, thanks!  Regarding concatenation, I agree it's expensive in general, but I don't see where a char[] can best replace it here, since the final string length depends on how many escapes are needed within it.  I suppose you could loop through the string chars twice to pre-calculate then apply to a fixed char[], but I'm not sure that's much faster, and certainly extra code that is less clear and could invite bugs.  Or were you looking at the "+" used in the helper function?

Comment: @ChrisJanicki I'm talking about maintaining a list of hex characters like `"0123456789abcdef".getChars()" and indexing into that instead of doing `"0" + s` in your `to2CharHexString` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably escape values in an LDAP filter provided by the caller if that filter represents the final filter to be used for the query. Consider the following filter assembled by the caller:

```
String value = "*)(objectClass=*";
String filter = "(|(attr1=constvalue)(attr2=" + value + "))";
search(filter);
```

The resulting filter matches all objects because the code does not escape `value`:

```
(|(attr1=constvalue)(attr2=*)(objectClass=*))
```

There is no way to escape `value` based on the final filter because the start and end position cannot be identified anymore.

To resolve this ambiguity and filter injection issue, the input values must be escaped while building the filter, not afterwards. However, this does not mean that the caller has to deal with escaping details directly - that's error-prone, so I don't recommend that.

All it takes for the EJB to handle escaping is knowing the desired filter including placeholders instead of actual values and a list of values. Java's `DirContext` already provides a mechanism you can take advantage of. `DirContext.search` has a `filterExpr` parameter that represents a filter template that can contain placeholders and a `filterArgs` parameter representing a list of corresponding values.

With that, the example above would turn into:

```
String value = "*)(objectClass=*";
String filter = "(|(attr1=constvalue)(attr2={0}))";
search(filter, new String[] { value });
```

Implementation of `search`:

```
dircontext.search(basedn, filter, valuearray, null);
```

That is the best compromise I can think of. It fully addresses LDAP filter injection issues, yet it does not require the caller to handle escaping, the caller only has to provide a filter template and a list of values.

Generally, using library facilities for escaping should be preferred over custom code to ensure that all cases are handled correctly. The other two answers illustrate that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine:

```
    static public string LDAPEscape(string s)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            char c = s[i];
            if ("/*)(\\\0".IndexOf(c) >= 0)
                sb.Append('\\').Append(((uint)c).ToString("x2"));
            else
                sb.Append(c);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If using maven repository [apache-ldap-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.directory.api/apache-ldap-api) as LDAP client library, we can use Util class [FilterEncoder](https://nightlies.apache.org/directory/api/1.0.2/apidocs/org/apache/directory/api/ldap/model/filter/FilterEncoder.html) to handle encoding of special characters in LDAP search filter values as below

```
filter = "(attributeKey=" + FilterEncoder.encodeFilterValue(attributeValue) + ")";
```